# Python 3 - looped thread creating multiple threads and not closing them

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

*I have already looked through many questions here in SO, so I don't think this is a duplicate, as most questions are regarding HOW to make thread-queue-loops, which I have already tried following with no success*

**The issue:**

I have a queue for threads that should only run one process at a time.

For that, I created a never-ending thread process with a `while True` in it.

This `while True` basically checks if a queue (simple list) has any items, then retrieves and runs them, removing them from the queue.

Everything is working alright, except by the fact that this code is generating thousands of open threads and never closing them, to a point where I start getting this error:

> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 844, in start
>
> _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
>
> RuntimeError: can't start new thread

From my perspective I only start threads once, and it handles method calls. It shouldn't spawn new threads.

What am I doing wrong?

**The code:**

```
import threading
import queue
[...]

class Monitor:
    [...]

    """
    Updates this monitor's ping indicator
    """
    def setLastMonitorPingIndicator(self):
        current_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%s')
        if (self.last_ping != current_timestamp):
            self.last_ping = current_timestamp
            # Inserting into the indicator table
            self.dbcursor.execute("""
                INSERT INTO
                    indicator (balance_id, name, value)
                VALUES
                    (NULL, %s, %s)
                ON CONFLICT
                    (name) WHERE balance_id IS NULL
                DO UPDATE SET
                    value = %s;""", ['last_balancemonitor_binance_ping', current_timestamp, current_timestamp])

    """
    Adds processes to threaded queue
    """
    def queueProcess(self, method, args=None):
        self._debug(4, "Queueing threaded method '"+method.__name__+"' ("+str(self.threadQueue.qsize())+" processes awaiting | "+str(self.threaded_processes_running)+" running)")
        self.threadQueue.put([method, args])

    """
    Processes queued threaded processes
    """
    def processThreadedQueue(self):
        while True:
            # wait for an item from the producer
            item = self.threadQueue.get()
            if item is None:
                continue

            self.threaded_processes_running = self.threaded_processes_running + 1

            method = item[0]

            now = time.time()
            self._debug(4, "Running '"+method.__name__+"' from threaded queue.")

            try:
                if item[1] is None:
                    method()
                else:
                    method(item[1])
            except Exception:
                print(traceback.format_exc())

            self._debug(4, "Finished running '"+method.__name__+"' from threaded queue. Took "+str(round((time.time()-now),2))+" seconds.")

            self.threaded_processes_running = self.threaded_processes_running - 1

    """
    Main method
    """
    def start(self):

        worker = threading.Thread(target=self.processThreadedQueue)
        worker.setDaemon(True) # Already tried with and without daemonizing it, same result
        worker.start()

        [...]

        while (True):

            [...]

            # Updating this monitor's ping
            self.queueProcess(self.setLastMonitorPingIndicator)

            sleep(5)

monitor = Monitor()
monitor.start()
```

Comment: What's the point of `asyncio` here? You're using multiple threads explicitly, so it's not the usual single-threaded concurrency design for which `asyncio` is most-commonly used.

Comment: asyncio here is just to keep the process running until canceled. You're saying I should just `monitor.start()` instead of using asyncio? I thought asyncio would make it run cleaner than leaving the infinite loop run per se.

Comment: Unless you really need all the extra stuff provided by `asyncio`, it seems to complicate things. It doesn't seem to matter in this case whether the loop is managed by `asyncio` or not. At least, not from the code you've posted here.

Comment: Perfect then, will remove it, thanks for the heads up. Not sure asyncio is the root cause of the too-many-threads issue though.

Comment: Removed asyncio, so far it's working, thanks. As expected, it didn't fix the main issue though.